# Prove the matrix identity $a^{T}Aa = \operatorname{tr}(Aaa^{T})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove the matrix identity: $a^T Aa = \operatorname{tr}(Aaa^{T})$

I tried to show the following: 
$a^T Aa = \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 a_j A_{ji}a_i$

I'm having trouble how the above is equal to  $\operatorname{tr}(Aaa^T)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe 
\begin{align}
(aa^T)_{ij} = a_ia_j 
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
(Aaa^T)_{ij} = \sum^n_{k=1}A_{ik}a_ka_j
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left(Aaa^T \right) = \sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{k=1}A_{ik}a_ka_i = a^TAa. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

If you know the identity $tr(CD)=tr(DC)$,

Notice that $a^TAa$ is a scalar, hence $a^TAa = tr(a^TAa)=tr(Aaa^T)$

where $C= a^T$ and $D=Aa$.

Comment: Thank you for the simple proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can show this by just computing both sides of the equation and conclude that they are the same. For example, $a^TAa = \sum_{i,j} a_ia_jA_{ij}$. Next, compute a generic entry of the matrix $Aaa^T$ and show that the sum of the diagonal entries is also the sum $\sum_{i,j} a_ia_jA_{ij}$.